# App SDK: Error parsing input stream when running query

Tags: javascript, web-services, rally

I'm using the App SDK to query all open defects within a specific project. I'm using `findAll` so I believe it should be returning all results but I'm only getting back 200. There's an error within the `OperationResult` that says:

> "Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: Read unexpected character 'u' while trying to read a property value. [ chars read = >>>{"defects":u<<< ]"

I haven't come across this before using queries that have returned much larger results than 200, this seems to be some sort of encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a defect we introduced a week or so ago in versions 1.27 and 1.28 of the App SDK.  It will be fixed this weekend (12/10/11).

Comment: I still face this in version 1.33

Comment: any suggestions ? btw I dont know why i can't use versions after 1.33 it makes exception when I initialize QueryResult

Comment: We have stopped releasing 1.x versions of the SDK in favor of the new 2.0 preview.  If you could post your code and a description of the problem in a new question we may be able to help.