# 'Cannot parse input stream' error when updating defects in Rally via pyral

Tags: python-2.7, rally

I am using the Python Toolkit for Rally REST API to update defects on our Rally server. I have confirmed that I am able to make contact with the server and authenticate fine by getting a list of current defects. I am running into issues with updating them. I am using Python 2.7.3 with pyral 0.9.1 and requests 0.13.3.

Also, I am passing 'verify=False' to the Rally() call and have made appropriate chages to the 
restapi module to compensate for this.

Here is my test code:

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallySettings

server = "rallydev.server1.com"
user = "user@mycompany.com"
password = "trial"
workspace = "trialWorkspace"
project = "Testing Project"
defectID = "DE192"

rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace,
              project=project,     verify=False)
defect_data = { "FormattedID" : defectID,
                "State"       : "Closed"
              }
try:
    defect = rally.update('Defect', defect_data)
except Exception, details:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s \n' % details)
    sys.exit(1)

print "Defect %s updated" % defect.FormattedID
```

When I run the script:

```
[temp]$ ./updefect.py  
ERROR: Unable to update the Defect
```

If I change the code in the RallyRESTResponse function to print out the value of self.errors when found (line 164 of rallyresp.py), I get this output:

```
[temp]$ ./updefect.py   
[u"Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '{' but saw '\uffff' [ chars read = >>>\uffff<<< ]"]  
ERROR: Unable to update the Defect
```

I did find another question that sounds like it might possibly be related to mine here:
[App SDK: Erorr parsing input stream when running query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450975/app-sdk-erorr-parsing-input-stream-when-running-query)

Can you provide any assistance?

Comment: I should add that the defectID listed is a real defect that I created in the appropriate real workspace and project via the web GUI. If I run the script with debug=on in the Rally call, I can see the issue occuring during the POST operation:  https://rallydev.server1.com/slm/webservice/1.30/defe ct/12345678.js?workspace=workspace/1234&project=project/12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pairing Michael's observation regarding the GZIP encoding with that of another astute Rally customer working a Support case on the issue - it appears that some versions of the requests module will default to GZIP compression if the content-type is not specifically defined.

The fix is to set content-type to application/json in the REST Headers section of pyral's config.py:

```
RALLY_REST_HEADERS = \
{
  'X-RallyIntegrationName'     : 'Python toolkit for Rally REST API',
  'X-RallyIntegrationVendor'   : 'Rally Software Development', 
  'X-RallyIntegrationVersion'  :       '%s.%s.%s' % __version__,
  'X-RallyIntegrationLibrary'  : 'pyral-%s.%s.%s' % __version__,
  'X-RallyIntegrationPlatform' : 'Python %s' % platform.python_version(),
  'X-RallyIntegrationOS'       : platform.platform(),
  'User-Agent'                 : 'Pyral Rally WebServices Agent',
  'Content-Type'               : 'application/json',
}
```

Comment: That would be it! I had to modify config.py to include the 'Content-Type' line. No more errors and I have confirmed the defect being updated on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is probably not related to the Python 2.7.3 / requests 0.13.3 versions being used.  The error message you saw has also been reported using the Javascript based App SDK and .NET Toolkit for Rally (2 separate reports here on SO) and at least one other person using Python 2.6.6 and requests 0.9.2.   It appears that the error verbiage is being generated on the Rally WSAPI back-end.  Current assessment by fellow Rally'ers is that it is an encoding  related issue.  The question is where the encoding issue originates.
I have yet to be able to repro this issue, having tried with several versions of Python (2.6.x and 2.7.x), several versions of requests and on Linux, MacOS and Win7.

As you seem to be pretty comfortable with diving in to the code and running in debug mode, one avenue to try is to capture the defective POST URL and POST data and attempting the update via a browser based REST client like 'Simple REST Client' or Poster and observing if you get the same error message in the WSAPI response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing similar behavior with pyral while trying to add an attachment to a defect.

With debugging and logging on I see this request on stdout:

```
2012-07-20T15:11:24.855212   PUT   https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.30/attachmentcontent/create.js?workspace=workspace/123456789
```

Then the json in the logfile:

```
2012-07-20 15:11:24.854 PUT attachmentcontent/create.js?workspace=workspace/123456789
                            {"AttachmentContent": {"Content": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBQAAAJrCAIAAADf2VflAAAXOWlDQ...
```

Then this in the logfile (after a bit of fighting with restapi.py to get around the unicode error):

```
2012-07-20 15:11:25.260 404 Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '{' but saw '?' [ chars read = >>>?<<< ]
```

The notable thing there is the **404** error code. Also, the "Cannot parse input stream..." error message is not coming from pyral, it's coming from Rally's server. So pyral is sending Rally something Rally can't understand.

I also logged the response headers, which may be a clue:

```
{'rallyrequestid': 'qs-app-03ml3akfhdpjk7c430otjv50ak.qs-app-0387404259', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:18:35 GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'cache-control': 'no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate', 'date': 'Fri, 20 Jul 2012 19:18:36 GMT', 'p3p': 'CP="NON DSP COR CURa PSAa PSDa OUR NOR BUS PUR COM NAV STA"', 'content-type': 'text/javascript;  charset=utf-8'}
```

Note there the 'content-encoding': 'gzip'. I suspect the requests module (I'm using 0.13.3 in Macos Python 2.6) is gzip encoding its PUT request but the Rally API server is not properly decoding that.

Comment: Good catch on the gzip encoding.